# Finding locally concave properties

Tags: calculus

Suppose that f is  a strictly increasing, strictly concave function on $\mathbb{R}$  and v is a function defined on $\mathbb{R}$, mapping into [0,1]. v is strictly increasing, but may convex on some regions (in particular it could be  a CDF) Let F be defined by:

$$F(x_1, x_2)=f(x_1)+f(x_2 v(x_1))$$.

I would like to show, under which additional assumptions, we can have that that $\forall x,y$, whenever $F(x)=F(y)$, then $\exists\alpha$ such that $F(\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y)>F(x)$, that is some form of local concavity.

Let $x^\alpha=\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y$. I believe that one can show that finding such an $\alpha$ then implies that we need $\alpha$ such that:

$$\alpha\left[f\left(x_{2}v\left(x_{1}^{\alpha}\right)\right)-f\left(x_{2}v(x_{1})\right)\right]+\left(1-\alpha\right)\left[f\left(y_{2}v\left(x_{1}^{\alpha}\right)\right)-f\left(y_{2}v(y_{1})\right)\right]\geq0$$

I have been stuck here for a while. Is there anything that I can impose upon the relative concavity of f versus the possible convexity of f, knowing that v maps into [0,1] and is strictly increasing that ensures the existence of some $\alpha\in(0,1)$ such that this property holds?

Many, many thanks in advance!

Comment: In particular, $v(x)=\frac{1}{1+ke^{-kx}}$, if it is of any help, where $k$ is a parameter.